# Modify CSS Applied to Hover State

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am wondering how I would be able to modify an existing style that is applied to the hover state of an element via jQuery.

For example:

```
.button { color:red; }
.button:hover { color:blue; }
```

I would like to apply the style `font-size:14px;` to `.button:hover`. The value of font-size will vary depending on which other elements on the page the user has interacted with previously.

Comment: modify...where? Adding it to the .button:hover css is out of the question I assume?

Comment: Why using jquery for this? use with css instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify the `:hover` styles (or any other psuedo-class) using JavaScript, because technically they aren't part of the DOM.

What you'll need to do is add those styles to a different class in your CSS, then add/remove that class using JavaScript/jQuery.

CSS:

```
.button.bigger { font-size:14px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.button').on('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('bigger');
});
```

Comment: As always, keep in mind that your hover styles won't work on touchscreen devices.

Comment: Thats OK. I'm just building for desktop :)

Comment: Oh I was too slow. +1 for being much quicker! :)

Answer (score 2):

what about this with css:

```
.button:hover { color:blue; font-size:14px;}
```

and with jQuery:

```
 $('.button').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({"font-size":"14px"}); // increases on mouseover
 },function(){
    $(this).css({"font-size":"12px"}); // decreases on mouseout
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

add some class or id to your button..target it using jquery and add css to it.

e.g.

```
$('.buttonToBeChanged').on('hover',function(){
    $(this).css('font-size',14);
});
```

That should do. See this for reference. http://api.jquery.com/css/

EDIT : The code will set the font to 14px after that. even after hover out. To give it a toggle effect, use the answer by @Blazemonger. That is just fine. Or you can use **mouseenter** and **mouseout** events

EDIT AGAIN - CSS too will do the job alone as @Jai mentioned.

```
.button:hover { color:blue; font-size:14px;}
```

Comment: `hover` may take 2 functions as arguments. In that case it is a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. If you pass solely one function, it will attach the same function to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Thats right! absolutely. I just showed a way. Now the answer has been edited to answer all the queries.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to either make an event handler in jQuery or make a class specific hover in CSS.

Here is a working example of both:

http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/GHzSs/

JS:

```
$('#large').hover(function(e) {
        var t = $(this);
        t.css('fontSize', '14px');
}, function(e) {
        var t = $(this);
        t.css('fontSize', '11px');
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button">Regular Button</div>
<div class="button large">Large Button (by class/css)</div>
<div class="button" id="large">Large Button (by id/jquery)</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.large:hover {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```